# Actionscript 3.0: How to add code to pixels copied via BitmapData

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmapdata

My question is if I can add eventListeners to the pixels I copied with the instance.copyPixels... If I perhaps copy my character from bitmap I have loaded. Can I make him walk?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using?

Comment: I was learning by watching this tutorial. http://tinyurl.com/nmxmw5a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to draw the moving parts into different `Sprites` and then move those arround.
This is the wrong approach though.
Walking animations for example are usualy done with a `SpriteSheet` and `Blitting` or `BitmapData Frame assignment`.